# What websites upload and sell online records of guitar and piano music?

Tags: recording, production

Can you advise, please, what websites upload and sell online original records of guitar and piano music (authored by unknown players) ?
How much to pay for that and what websites are known as fake and fraud designed to fool music artists?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: You might want to use some platforms that make the music accessible for free, for at least a few tracks, to build a following or let people "sample" your style.

Comment: I have to vote to close because of the topic but pretty much any music platform nowadays allows artists to create an account and upload and present their music. You don’t have to be known or have a record deal to get your music out there.